# python re how to search end of the digit from sting?

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, python-re

How to search end of the digit from this two srting which is  0.12%?

```
text1 = '20% of the modern marijuana terpene profile. Myrcene has a distinct earthy, musky flavor, resembling cloves. It is responsible for calming and soothing effects of weed. Myrcene is also found in hops, thyme, mango, lemongrass, guava melon.     0.12%'



text2 = 'The modern marijuana terpene profile. Myrcene has a distinct earthy, musky flavor, resembling cloves. It is responsible for calming and soothing effects of weed. Myrcene is also found in hops, thyme, mango, lemongrass, guava melon.     0.12%'
```

I tried this which worked for text2 but not getting expected result for text1 like text2

```
re.search(r'(\d.*)',text)
```

but my expected result will be  `0.12%` only

Comment: Try `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$` https://regex101.com/r/SkxBNC/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `(\d.*)` captures the first encounter of a digit followed by the rest of the line.

To match the digit with an optional decimal part followed by a percentage sign at the end of the string:

```
\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$
```

**Explanation**

- `\b` A word boundary to prevent a partial word match
- `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match 1+ digits with an optional decimal part
- `%` Match literally
- `$` End of string

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/v0KAw3/1)

Comment: The fourth bird what's does `:` clone doing here?

Comment: @boyenec The `(?:` construct is a non capture group. So this part `(?:\.\d+)` groups a dot and 1 or mor digits and the following `?` makes the whole grouping optional.

Answer (score 0):

> `\b\d+(?:\.\d+)?%$`

This should work.

`\b` Returns a match where the specified characters are at the beginning or at the end of a word

`\d` Returns a match where the string contains digits (numbers from 0-9) [Checks for digits basically]

`+` One or more occurrences

`()` Capture and group

- `?` Zero or one occurrences
- `\d` Returns a match where the string contains digits (numbers from 0-9)
- `+` One or more occurrences

`?` Zero or one occurrences

`%$` Checks if ends with `%`

Some explanation taken from [w3schools](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_regex.asp)